# Prime gap size of order square root p(n)

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, prime-gaps

I have the below construction.

Take a standard parabola $y=x^2$ with points on the x-axis at $(-p_n,0)$ and $(p_{n+1},0)$ and corresponding points on the parabola of $(-p_n,p_n^2)$ and $(p_{n+1},p_{n+1}^2)$ respectively. The following follows regarding the point that lies on the secant intersecting the points on the parabola and the y-axis $(0,p_np_{n+1})$

$\forall p_n\in\mathbb{P},$  $p_{n}^2 \leq p_np_{n+1}$
$\implies p_{n} \leq \sqrt{p_n}\sqrt{p_{n+1}}$
$\implies p_{n}-p_{n-1} \leq \sqrt{p_n} \sqrt{p_{n+1}} - p_{n-1}$
$\implies g_{n} <\sqrt{p_n}$

Is it correct that the secant line will pass through the y-axis at the point indicated in the above construction?

Edit:

It would appear one could achieve a tighter bound by considering $(-\sqrt{g_n},0)$ and $(\frac{\sqrt{p_n}}{\sqrt{g_n}}\log({p_n}),0)$ which gives:

$g_n < \sqrt{p_n}\log{(p_n)}$

Which has some connection to the RZH by a result proved by Cramer?!

Edit2:
If I change the points in the original construction to $(-\sqrt{g_n},0)$ and $(\frac{\sqrt{p_n}}{\sqrt{g_n}},0)$ the original result appears to fall out by considering the secant line point on the y-axis and the left point on the parabola.

Comment: This seems unsupported to me. Why should $g_{n} \leq \sqrt{p_n} \sqrt{p_{n+1}} - p_{n-1}$ imply $g_{n} <\sqrt{p_n}$? Why should $g_n <  (p_n - p_{n-1}) \sqrt{p_n}\log{p_n}$ imply $g_n < \sqrt{p_n}\log{p_n}$?

Comment: Do I need to show more work? $g(n)^2 < p(n)(p(n) - g(n)) when p(n) - g(n) = p(n-1)$ Maybe I fuddled it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is : yes, the intersection point is $(0,p_np_{n+1})$.

Here is how one can prove it.

The equation of the line passing through two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is given by the following condition (expressing two ways to express the slope of the line) :

$$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

otherwise written :

$$y-y_1=\tfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$$

Set now $(x_1,y_1)=(-p_n,p_n^2)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(p_{n+1},p_{n+1}^2)$ ; you will obtain, after simplification the equation of the line under the form :

$$y-p_n^2=(p_{n+1}-p_n)(x+p_n)$$

in which you will set $x=0$ for the obtention of the value of $y$ which is indeed $p_np_{n+1}$.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the purpose of your implications, and the connection with prime numbers gaps. Could you say more on it ?

Comment: It seems gaps can have an upper bound based on this construction. ?!

Comment: This construction of the geometric mean using a parabola is known : see [here](https://www.mathrecreation.com/2015/09/geometric-mean-and-sieve.html) where, moreover, it is applied as a prime number sieve.

Comment: I have finally understood : indeed, you are concerned by an upper bound. This wasn't clear to me at first look.

Comment: Just corrected an error : I had introduced square roots that have nothing to do here (one deals with geometric means when one comes back to the $x$-axis using the inverse function of the square function).